# Girl Hackers - Logic Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

[image: Girl Hackers]

### StackExchange Top Ranked Girl Hackers

The **Stack Exchange Hacking Federation** (of course fictitious) has just released its list of top-ranked female hackers for the year.

Using only the clues below, match each hacker to her number of wins (un-crackable programs she wrote) and losses ( programs she wrote that WERE cracked )  and determine the city where she lives and writes her code.

### Clues

1. The hacker with 36 wins isn't from Portland.
2. The hacker from Los Angeles is either Yvonne Ware or the hacker with 4 losses.
3. Yvonne Ware is from Miami.
4. Hannah Hak has fewer wins than the hacker from Boston.
5. Diane DeAscii has 3 more wins than the hacker with 12 losses.
6. Of the hacker from Philadelphia and the hacker with 33 wins, one is Yvonne Ware and the other has 12 losses.
7. The hacker from Miami has 9 more wins than the hacker with 12 losses.
8. The hacker with 2 losses, Gina Giffy, and the hacker from Boston are three different people.
9. Gina Giffy has 8 losses.
10. The hacker with 36 wins, the hacker from Boston, and the hacker from Philadelphia are three different people.

**Important:** 
Remember, no option in any category will  be used more than once.

#### Categories

GIRLS: Diane DeAscii , Edna Exec, Gina Giffy, Hannah Hak, Yvonne Ware

CITIES: Boston, Miami, LA, Philly, Portland

WINS: 24, 27, 30, 33, 36

LOSSES: 2, 4, 8, 10, 12

Comment: I was about to start my answer by organizing the info, and then you did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: oh boy, it's Brandon_J - My puzzle cracked before I hit Submit. LOL Good luck, this one is challenging ( a bit ). Anyone who wants the answer, let me know, I will send it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution:

1. > Yvonne Ware.  Wins : 33   Losses:2. Place: Miami
2. > Hannah Hak. Wins : 24   Losses:12. Place: Philadelphia
3. > Diane de ASCII.  Wins : 27   Losses:10 Place: Boston
4. > Gina Griffy.  Wins : 30 Losses:8. Place: Portland
5. > Edna exec Wins : 36  Losses:4  Place: Los Angeles

Verification from clues:

The hacker with 36 wins isn't from Portland.

> Edna exec (36w) is not from Portland

The hacker from Los Angeles is either Yvonne Ware or the hacker with 4 losses.

> Yvonne Ware is from Miami (given) so hacker with 4 losses is (Edna) is from LA

Yvonne Ware is from Miami.

> A direct clue

Hannah Hak has fewer wins than the hacker from Boston.

> Hannah Hak has 24 while hacker from Boston has 27

Diane DeAscii has 3 more wins than the hacker with 12 losses.

> The same (27 and 24). So now Hannah has 12 losses

Of the hacker from Philadelphia and the hacker with 33 wins, one is Yvonne Ware and the other has 12 losses.

> Yvonne isn't from Philadelphia, so she has 33 wins.and the one with 12 losses, Hannah is from Philadelphia

The hacker from Miami has 9 more wins than the hacker with 12 losses.

> Yvonne has 33, so Hannah should have 24

The hacker with 2 losses, Gina Giffy, and the hacker from Boston are three different people.

> They are Yvonne, Gina and Diane de ascii

Gina Giffy has 8 losses.

> Another direct clue

The hacker with 36 wins, the hacker from Boston, and the hacker from Philadelphia are three different people.

> They are Edna , Diane nand Hannah

Comment: Awesome work @Tojrah! Of course I mean good work on YOUR HACKING skills, cuz you had to be watching my keystrokes as I made the puzzle. ;0